# Does suffero have perfect forms?

Tags: perfect-tense

I read in "A Grammar of the Latin Language" by Karl Gottlob Zumpt that suffero has no perfect or supine because sustuli is for tollo. However [I found perfect forms in online grammars](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-dictionary-flexion.php?lemma=SUFFERO100). So, for example, *sustinuit* would mean "he suffered" according to the online grammars, but does not exist according to Zumpt. Who is right?

Answer (score 5):

The form *sustuli* appears under the entries for both *[tollo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=tollo&la=la#lexicon)* and *[suffero](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=suffero&la=la#lexicon)* in *Lewis and Short*. However, *[sustinuit](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sustinuit&la=la#lexicon)* is a form of *sustineo*, and not of *suffero* (contrary to what the link you provided says). Since *Lewis and Short* is more authoritative, I believe the site that you linked to should be considered incorrect.

My take on this is that Cicero's usage was exceptional, but it became acceptable because he set the precedent. In the first place, Zumpt seems to consider it exceptional:

> *Suffero* has no perfect or supine, for *sustuli*, *sublatum*, belong to *tolo*. Cicero, however (N. D., iii., 33) has *poenas sustulit*,
> but *sustinui* is commonly used in this sense. (*A Grammar of the Latin Language*, pg. 182)

In addition to Zumpt's comment, Henri J. W. Wijsman referred to Cicero's usage, saying:

> **249 (ictum) sustuli** not from *tollere* but from *suffere*! Compare Stat. *Theb.* 8.657 f. *primos veluti modo comminus ictus/ sustulerint*. Cic. *N.D.* 3.82 *at Phalaris, at Apollodorus poenas sustulit* is
> slightly different in that they did not so much show endurance, as
> have to suffer the consequences of their misbehaviour. (*[Valerius Flaccus, Argonautica, Book VI: A Commentary](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=gqOODwAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22Apollodorus%20poenas%20sustulit%22&source=bl&ots=q6erM9diOF&sig=ACfU3U0L3pD1kFWR4pV5eGzsaWo0JTtTFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZwfSQ7IjzAhVvqpUCHSejBUg4ChDoAXoECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22Apollodorus%20poenas%20sustulit%22&f=false)*)

Therefore, if Wijsman is correct, this usage of *sustulit* should be taken as a perfect form of *suffero*.

Comment: In other words, don't believe random internet websites.

Comment: @cmw The big question is: Is this site a random internet website too? I sure hope not.

Comment: @cmw I believe this is at least the third time that we have seen online-latin-dictionary.com confusing people with blatant errors. (Although in this case, I can see how one could take a comment like "sustinui is commonly used in this sense" the wrong way.)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel This is the only place I've ever seen it mentioned. Why on earth would anyone use it over reputable sources is far beyond me. Even the site visually looks suspect.

Comment: @cmw A well-chosen domain name makes all the difference, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

*Sufferō* is an interesting case.

*Ferō* "bear" on its own is quite a common verb. For whatever reason, its perfect forms fell out of use, and it stole perfect forms from *tollō* "lift"; this is a not uncommon process, and is how we got present "go" with past "went" (stolen from "wend") in English.

The perfect forms of *tollō* then became ambiguous—was *lātus* "borne" or "lifted"? So *tollō* took the perfect forms from the compound *sustollō* "lift up", which were unambiguously about lifting, and those two verbs somewhat merged into one: *tollō* in the present, *sustulī* in the perfect.

But this created a new ambiguity, when *ferō* got compounded. We would expect the perfect of *sufferō* to be *sustulī*—but that form is now also used by *tollō*! Since *tollō* was by far the more common verb, people generally used *sustulī* only with the *tollō* meaning, and used other verbs if they wanted to unambiguously indicate *sufferō*—if this trend continued, it's possible we would have seen even more suppletion, with *sufferō* stealing perfect forms from yet another verb like *sustineō*.

However, things didn't end up developing this way. As Expedito Bipes explains, Cicero (and apparently also Statius) chose to use *sustulī* as the perfect of *sufferō*, and Cicero's influence was far-reaching. Lewis and Short thus associate *sustulī* with both of those verbs.

Comment: According to Sihler § 485, there is no perfect or aorist form of **bher-*. So in that sense, *fero* didn't lose a perfect stem, it never had one to begin with!

Comment: @cmw Fascinating—how old does that lack of perfect/aorist seem to be? All the way back to PIE?

Comment: I was just looking into the same question as @cmw :) Apparently only Indo-Iranian has a reduplicated perfect from *bher-, and that's thought to be an innovation rather than a PIE inheritance (though I don't know why). LIV also lists possible aorists in Vedic and Old Irish, which may again be innovations.

Comment: @TKR Very fascinating. I'm tempted to ask a new question about it, though between these two comments it's been answered pretty well already.