# What does "ensem sufferre" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Roma Aeterna*: Ch. 37 Line 173:

> Cui (*=Priamō*) Pyrrhus “Nunc morere!” inquit, senemque ... ad ipsam āram trāxit, ubi laevā comam eius prehendēns dextrā ***ēnsem sustulit*** atque in latere rēgis dēfīxit!

***sufferre*** means "to offer" "to put under" or "to suffer" according to dictionaries, but the agent of ***sustulit*** seems to be Pyrrhus, who wanted to kill Priamus. Is there any reason that "he *offered* (/*suffered*/...) the sword with right hand"?

Comment: Rogō prius responsum accipiās tē 24 hōrās opperīrī ut aliī peritiōrēs alternātum prōpōnere possint—praesertim sī responsum illum ego scripsī. Latīnē tīrō sum; capitulum profectō idem Ørbergiī quod legis nunc legō!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The verb that is intended here is almost certainly [tollo, tollere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DT%3Aentry+group%3D24%3Aentry%3Dtollo), which shares third and fourth principal parts with *sufferre**. Although *sufferre* can, according to *Lewis & Short*, mean 'hold up,' the entry also notes that this sense of the verb is 'very rare.' On the other hand, meanings such as 'pick up,' 'raise,' and 'lift' are primary for *tollere*.

Here, Pyrrhus 'lifted the sword with his right hand' as a preliminary to stabbing it into Priam's body.

* For the reason why this is the case, see, for example, [Does suffero have perfect forms?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16863/does-suffero-have-perfect-forms)

Comment: Sānē responsum tuum rectius est. Auctor quaestiōnis mox regredi atque eum accipere spērēmus.

Answer (score 7):

"…with his right hand he **held up the sword**…"

See sense II.B in [*Lewis & Short*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=suffero), "To hold up, bear, support, sustain."

The *sub-* prefix here means "up". Amazingly, *sub* is cognate with English "up". [Here's](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/5656/118) an explanation of the connection, with more examples.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth mentioning that sustulit is also the perfect of tollere. I suspect that's actually the verb that's intended in the passage.

Comment: @cnread Hmm, how would you like to post that as a separate answer? I had completely forgotten that _sustulit_ is also the perfect of _tollere_. I'll also post a comment suggesting waiting 24 hours before accepting an answer. Come to think of it, I don't think that Ørberg has introduced the verb _sufferō_ yet.